# stop onclick javascript function from repeating my rows in table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button -

`<a onclick="function edit_row()"></a>`

When I click the button it invokes the function `edit_row` and opens a new row in a table which I can edit.

The problem is that every time I click the button, it opens a new row. I want to stop that. I want it to just open one row which holds the row id.

Script code:

```
function edit_row(process_id, row_id, item_id, quantity, price, total) {
    $(".edit_row").remove();
    $(".add_row").remove();
    var row = '<tr class="bg-success"> <
        td > <?php echo $lang['e_edit_items'];?>: < /td> <
        td > '+ item_id +' < /td>';
    row += '<td><?php echo $lang['
    quantity '];?></td>';
    row += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="quant1" value="' + quantity + '"></td><td><?php echo $lang['
    The - price '];?></td>';
    row += '<td><input type="text" id="price1"  class="form-control"  value="' + price + '"></td>';
    row += '<td><a   class="btn btn-success btn-block"onclick="save_edit(' + process_id + ',' + row_id + ',' + item_id + ',' + quantity + ',' + total + ')"><?php echo $lang['
    Save_edit '];?></a></td></tr>';
    $("#" + row_id).after(row);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: so have this function disable itself, or remove the button, or something...

Comment: easiest way is to add a flag like rowExists, set it when you add a new row and in the function put if(rowExists)return and do nothing. Set it back to false when you want the function to work again, like when the edit is done

Comment: Can you show us more of your code? How are you passing the parameters to the function? I don't see it in your `<a>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove click event handler of clickable element like this example.

```js
$("#button1").click(function(){
    $("table").append("<tr><td>New-1</td><td>New-2</td><td>New-3</td></tr>");
    $(this).unbind("click");
});
```

```css
table, tr, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="button1">Add row</a>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Column-1</td>
        <td>Column-2</td>
        <td>Column-3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Column-1</td>
        <td>Column-2</td>
        <td>Column-3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But there is many way to do this work. For example you can add `disabled` attribute to clickable element, if it is `button`, You can add `data-*` attribute or `class` to element or use variable to do this. See example of other way in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ykw53460/)